# React Native Geolocation watchPosition() documentation

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, geolocation

The documentation seems rather ambiguous and a tad minimalist on this API by React Native.
So I just want to clarify some things with those who have experience in using React Native's Geolocation API:

1. What's the use of `clearWatch()` method if what we need to unsubscribe from `watchPosition()` is `stopObserving()`? Do we need both to properly unsubscribe?
2. Does `watchPosition()` run when the app is in background by default or do we need to do background setup explicitly? (I do not need it to run on background just when the app is in use, hence the third question)
3. If it does run in the background by default, I know we need to set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` for IOS' `info.plist`, but is there any special setup for Android?

Thanks in advance for any Information on these 3 questions that has been bugging me! :D